# What does "get your account of events out there" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

> Reputation building involves telling and retelling your story to get
>   your account of events out there and to explain your downfall. Be
>   consistent.

Could you tell me please what's the meaning of "get your account of events out there"?

It would be so grateful if you could explain the sentence meaning too.

The fuller text:

> One of the most important steps on the route to recovery is to
>   confront and acknowledge failure. This can be as simple as
>   understanding the Machiavellian politics of others. So as you set
>   about rebuilding your career, make sure you:
>
> • Remember that failure
>   is a beginning, not an end. Comeback is always possible.
>
> • Look to the future.
>
> Preemptive actions are often more eff ective than reactive
>   ones—even if they only take the form of standing back and refl ecting
>   on what to do next.
>
> • Help people deal with your failure. Even close
>
> friends may avoid you because they don’t know what to say or do. Let
>   them know that you are ready for assistance and what kind of aid would
>   be most useful.
>
> • Know your narrative. Reputation building involves
>   telling and retelling your story to   **get your account of events out
>   there** and to explain your downfall. Be consistent.

http://daviddarmawan.blogspot.com/2008/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is easy to parse, as long as you know the idioms. It breaks down basically as

> get (your account of events) out there

The key idiom is "**to get X out there**". If you're trying to "get your product out there", you are trying to have your product where people can buy it, talk about it, etc. It was "in here", in your head or your workshop or your organisation, but you want it "out there". A publicist will talk about "getting your story out there", and politicians will often abbreviate it slightly to "getting our message out".

In this case, the X is "your account of events". An *account*, in this sense, is a version of a story, the way one person tells it. You might give an account of your typical day, which would describe all the things you do on a typical day.

So, getting your account of events out there is the process of making sure that *your* version of a story - in this case the story of your 'downfall' - is known to everyone, that it ideally dominates any other version of the story.